# How to run a single .feature file in a Playwright + Cucumber automation testing framework?

Tags: javascript, automation, cucumber, playwright, test-framework

I create Automation testing framework with Playwright + Cucumber.js written in Javascript language.
Everytime I type `npm run test` in the Console all the Cucumber scenarios (.feature files) are ran. But how can I run only one .feature scenario? Is there a command for this?

It would be really nice if you give me a tip how to run tests with tags, too.

I tried to run different commands but didn't succeed in running a single .feature test.

I tried to run tests with tags, but couldn't do it.

Comment: If you have a cucumber config file setup you can specify the feature file you want to run there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, for running one feature it`s

`npm run test <FullPathOfFeature>.feature`

For running even only one scenario in feature it`s

`npm run test <FullPathOfFeature>.feature:<LineOfCodeWhereScenarioIsDefined>`